# How to reset root password of mysql?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, magento

Story:
I have deployed 2 wordpress sites using IIS - Web Platform Installer. Now I want to add a Magento site. Since there's no Magento in Web Platform Installer, I need it to install manually (copy the magento folder to inetpub/wwwroot).

Now, it asks me to create a database in mysql. However, I forgot the root password. Basically, I know how to reset the password in mysql but when I stop the MySQL service, the wordpress sites stops working as well. My actual question is, if I reset the root password of mysql and change it to something else, would my wordpress sites continue to work? Or do I need to re-configure it and how?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a programming question. MySQL server maintenance and administration issue combined with Magento administration issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have access to the wordpress config file? It'll have the username and password for the database inside of it. wp-config.php in the root of the wordpress site.

This will either tell you your root password or if you're using a different user and can change the root password. If you want to indeed change the password, once confirming you will not break your wordpress sites (or not needing to because it tells you the password), the following link walks you through resetting the password: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html. I assume windows, based on IIS.

Comment: Just found out that the 2 wordpress sites uses different DB_NAME, DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD. So is it safe to reset the root password of mysql since they aren't using root as their DB_USER? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your root MySQL password on your server shouldn't effect the username/password referenced in wp_users in the database itself. If at any point you have to restart MySQL on the server, the site will not be able to connect to it until the service is started.

If you are referring to resetting that password, you need to go to wp_users and edit the row for the specific user. Type in a new password and set the hash to MD5 next to the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you change MySQL root password and some instance of Wordpress is using the user 'root' to access the database, so you will end up crashing Wordpress.

In this case, you can just edit file **wp-config.php** at the root directory where WP is installed, and change line `define('DB_PASSWORD', 'oldpassword')` to match your new password. Before doing this change, look to the previous line in this file and see if it looks like `define('DB_USER', 'root')`, indicating that you are really using 'root' user on Wordpress. If you are using some other user, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Just found out that the 2 wordpress sites uses different DB_NAME, DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD. So is it safe to reset the root password of mysql since they aren't using root as their DB_USER? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Resetting root password do not affect other users passwords.